# divs not behaving properly

Tags: html, css

What am I doing wrong? here is the HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="header">
    <p id="title">PNR File Finish</p>
</div>
    <div id="leftside">
        <form>
            <div>
                <label for="comp_Name">Company:<br/> <input id="comp_name" type="text" value="" name="" size="30"
                                                            maxlength="50"><br/><br/>
                <label for="nick">Company Code:<br/> <input id="nick" type="text" value="" name="" size="4"
                                                                maxlength="4"><br/><br/>
                <label for="clientID">ClientID:<br/> <input id="clientID" type="text" value="" name="" size="10"
                                                                    maxlength="10"><br/><br/>
                <label for="Recloc">Record Loc:<br/> <input id="recloc" type="text" value="" name=""
                                                                        size="10" maxlength="6"><br/><br/>
                <p id="info">Please be sure Client Name and Client ID are correct before running File
                                    Finishing!</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-md active" role="button">Run File Finish</a>
                <hr>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-md active" role="button">Reload PNR</a><br /><br />
                <p id="info2">If Customer information is incorrect, reload underlying PNR</p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="right_box">

    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

And here is the css:

```
body {
    background-color: white;
}

.container{
    width: 1200px;
    height: 800px;
    backround-color: #FAEBD7;
}

#header{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: darkblue;
}

#title{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

#leftside{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    height: 600px;
    border-left:    1px solid darkblue;
    border-right:  1px solid darkblue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid darkblue;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;

}

#right_box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 600px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid darkblue;

}
```

Right box is appearing both in and well below instead on right. I've tried many different ways, but cannot get it to work. Sorry, fairly new at this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have a ton of html errors, including a number of unclosed elements, which is probably causing that issue. Validate your html at https://validator.w3.org and see if you can clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have syntax errors, here is it cleaned up and (hopefully) working as intended.

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.container {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;
  backround-color: #FAEBD7;
}

#header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#leftside {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  height: 600px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkblue;
  border-right: 1px solid darkblue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid darkblue;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#right_box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="header">
    <p id="title">PNR File Finish</p>
  </div>
  <div id="leftside">
    <form>
      <div>
        <label for="comp_Name">Company:<br>
     <input id="comp_name" maxlength="50" name="" size="30" type="text" value=""><br>
     <br>
     <label for="nick">Company Code:<br>
     <input id="nick" maxlength="4" name="" size="4" type="text" value=""><br>
     <br>
     <label for="clientID">ClientID:<br>
     <input id="clientID" maxlength="10" name="" size="10" type="text" value=""><br>
     <br>
     <label for="Recloc">Record Loc:<br>
     <input id="recloc" maxlength="6" name="" size="10" type="text" value=""><br>
     <br></label></label>
        </label>
        </label>
        <p id="info"><label for="comp_Name">Please be sure Client Name and Client ID are correct before running File Finishing!</label></p><label for="comp_Name"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-md active" href="#" role="button">Run File Finish</a></label>
        <hr>
        <label for="comp_Name"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-md active" href="#" role="button">Reload PNR</a><br>
     <br></label>
        <p id="info2"><label for="comp_Name">If Customer information is incorrect, reload underlying PNR</label></p>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="right_box">
    <label for="comp_Name"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses. I test this out tomorrow.

Comment: @user2774415 click the "Run code snippet" button to see the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You have simply missed closing your div tag inside your form tag that is holding the input elements.

Comment: Using Shaun's example, I got this to work. Thank you all for your contributions.